# Link to get one level up in mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki

In my mediawiki I have one page with the following links:

PageA:
LinkToPageB
LinkToPageC
LinkToPageD

Now, when I am on PageB, is there anything I can do to get a link to get to the next level, in this case, to PageA?

Thanks alot in advance.
Wolfgang

Comment: can you make it clear what you want to do?? do you want that there magically be a link to pageA in pageB??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this would be to make PageB a sub-page of PageA. Then PageB would have a link back to PageA at the top of the page.  See [the subpages help documentation](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aSubpages) for more information.  You have to set the variable [$wgNamespacesWithSubpages](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgNamespacesWithSubpages) to include whatever namespace you want to use subpages in (like the main namespace for example).  Then you can name your pages:

```
PageA
PageA/PageB
PageA/PageC
PageA/PageD
```

and the subpages will have a link back to PageA at the top of the page.